# I would appreciate some help improving the following question

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, quality-improvement

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268757/python-user-input-as-a-function-argument-not-working-typeerror-not-suppor) 6 months ago and I am not sure why it deserves a negative score. It appears that my question was already answered by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers), but I know that before posting a question, I usually look for an answer, but apparently didn't find the one suggested here.
I believe that it is because my research was not formulated in a way that was close to that particular question's title, and therefore it didn't appear in the search results.

That being said, how can I improve my question now, to make it more acceptable, and maybe bring it back to at least a score of 0?

Comment: No one but whoever downvoted could tell you why it was downvoted. At a guess it's because typing the error into google gives half a million results.

Comment: [Googling the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+'<'+not+supported+between+instances+of+'int'+and+'str') provides [another post with the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41950042/4642212) as the first result. The question, your question was closed as a duplicate of, has [524 linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/20449427), so ca. 500 others have asked this question — that’s not even counting the deleted ones. All this means: lack of research effort. Your question may no longer be salvageable.

Comment: One thing to be aware of; when asking for interpretation of downvotes on a question from Meta, the question is likely to be met with the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/215552), which is additional scrutiny from others. That could bring more downvotes to your question.

Comment: I don't think the question here is asking help interpreting the votes, but asking help in improving the question.

Comment: OK, I can understand that. It was a Rooky mistake for sure, and at the time I didn't really understand how stackoverflow worked. I believe I was thinking that you could ask whatever you wanted, a bit like on reddit, but focusd on coding.

Comment: @yivi, yes that was the goal, thank you :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is much way to improve the question, I'm afraid. Deleting it so it doesn't accrue further downvotes would be the better option, I think.

Comment: @yivi, thanks I appreciate the effort to help me here :)

Comment: Regarding your post-ban, if you are still post-banned, please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), if you haven't.

Comment: @yivi, thank you I have read it, but I have been banned for a while now, so I am trying to make it up to the community by cleaning up my mess... which I am apparently not succeeding :)

Comment: It wasn't possible with this particular question, maybe there is some other that would be a bit more borderline. If not, I'm afraid you'll have to wait until your next chance to ask a question and make the most out of it. Good luck!

Comment: @yivi Thank you, your help is very much appreciated :)
I think I will try to improve other questions by myself, it's less risky lol

Comment: I read that question and I'm not really sure why you've asked it. Between the error message (`'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`) and the fact that you've found converting the input to `int` fixes it, it seems like you have all the pieces to put it together. In the first edit you refer to a `year` function you don't show, which is also confusing.